# Remote Microsoft SQL Server Connection Security

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2003

I have access to a Virtual Server (Windows server 2003) where I am administering ASP.NET website and a MS-SQL Database.

Currently there are some security issues that are preventing me from connecting to the SQL Server from my personal PC. the reason I need to do this is because I have to sync the live database with the significant changes I have made on my local test database.

After days of trying to solve the security issue I email the server owners who then forwarded to a technician. His reply was this:

> What your IT guy is asking for is a violation of our IP security standards. We do not allow remote SQL connectivity, as this information is transmitted in clear text and is therefore not encrypted.

I have never heard of this and in every job as a .NET developer I have had, there has been remote connections via SQL Server manager to databases on different servers.

Is what he is saying true?

Comment: Since it's quite easy to force encryption to be used for all connections to the server, and this is configured in the same place that opening remote connections is, it sounds like a bit of laziness on his part to not *support* [encrypted connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx) (But yes, the default is that the data is sent in the clear - not usually an issue within an organisation)

Answer (score 1):

I assume this connection is going over the internet, between a PC at your home office and the VM belonging to your customer.

The solution is to setup up a RAS SSTP or PPTP VPN to your server. Dial up to the server over the VPN then connect to SQL server over the VPN connection.

(To answer the actual question, I believe that while the authentication is not in the clear, the data and commands will be. It is certainly possible to configure an IPSec secure connection policy to prevent this, but almost nobody knows how. The VPN is far easier.)

Comment: I have been trying this although I get stuck at setup since there is only one network connection on the server. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: @David, choose "Custom" and then "VPN". Also for PPTP or IPSec you need extra firewall rules. For SSTP you need a certificate.

Comment: The VPN has been set up using the Custom option. The firewall is turned off the the time being but I don't know what you mean about the SSTP certificate. I can only find articles relating to server2008, I am on 2003. How do I implement this?

Comment: THere is no SSTP in server 2003. You will have to use PPTP or L2TP. Don't turn off the firewall, just add the correct rules. See this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323441

Comment: I have followed that. When I try and connect I get: Error 800 -            The remote connection was not made because the attempted VPN tunnels failed. The VPN server might be unreachable. If this connection is attempting to use an L2TP/IPsec tunnel, the security parameters required for IPsec negotiation might not be configured properly.

Comment: @david, you need to ask that question on Server Fault.